# Calculator not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have completed this calculator using JS, I'm fairly new to JS, but when I finished my small project I  noticed it wouldn't append. Does anyone know where I went wrong?? I cannot find the bug pleaseeeeeeeeee hellppp.

I tried to append the numbers I'm pretty sure I did everything rights but there's a bug somewhere

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calculator-grid">
        <div class="output">
            <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div>
            <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
        </div>
        <button data-all-clear>C</button>
        <button data-operation>+/-</button>
        <button data-operation>%</button>
        <button data-operation>÷</button>
        <button data-number>7</button>
        <button data-number>8</button>
        <button data-number>9</button>
        <button data-number>X</button>
        <button data-number>4</button>
        <button data-number>5</button>
        <button data-number>6</button>
        <button data-operation>-</button>
        <button data-number>1</button>
        <button data-number>2</button>
        <button data-number>3</button>
        <button data-operation>+</button>
        <button data-number class="span-two">0</button>
        <button data-number>.</button>
        <button data-equals>=</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
class Calculator{
    constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement){
        this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement;
        this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
        this.clear()
    }

    clear() {
        this.currentOperand = ''
        this.previousOperand = ''
        this.operation = undefined
    }

    delete() {
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString().slice(1, -1)
    }

    appendNumber(number) {
        if(number === '.' && this.currentOperand.includes('.')) return
        this.currentNumber = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString() 
    }

    chooseOperation(operation) {
        if(this.currentOperand === '') return
        if(this.previousOperand !== '') {
            this.compute()
        }
        this.operation = operation
        this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand
        this.currentOperand = ''
    }

    compute() {
        let computation 
        const prev =parseFloat(this.previousOperand)
        const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand)
        if(isNaN(prev) || isNaN(current)) return
        switch (this.operation) {
            case '+':
                computation = prev + current
                break
            case '-':
                computation = prev - current
                break
            case '*':
                computation = prev * current
                break
            case '÷':
                computation = prev / current
                break
            default:
                return
        }
        this.currentOperand = computation
        this.operation = undefined
        this.previousOperand = ''
    }

    getDisplayNumber(number){
        const stringNumber = number.toString()
        const intergerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split('.')[0])
        const decimalDigits = stringNumber('.')[1]
        let intergerDisplay
        if(isNaN(intergerDigits)) {
            intergerDisplay = ''
        }else{
            intergerDisplay = intergerDigits.toLocaleString('en',{
                maximumFractionDigits:0 })
        }
        if(decimalDigits != null) {
            return `${intergerDisplay}.${decimalDigits}`
        }else{
            return intergerDisplay
        }
    }

    updateDisplay() {
        this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText =
        this.getDisplayNumber(this.currentOperand)
        if(this.operation != null){
        this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = 
        `${this.previousOperand} ${this.operation}`
        }
    }
};


const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]');
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]');
const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]');
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]');
const allClearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]');
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]');
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]');




const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
});

operationButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})

equalsButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
    calculator.compute()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})

allClearButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
    calculator.clear()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
    calculator.delete()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})
```

```
*, *::before, *::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.calculator-grid{
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
    grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
}

.calculator-grid > button{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid white;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

.calculator-grid > button:hover{
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, .9);
}

.span-two{
    grid-column: span 2;
}

.output{
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    height: 20vh;
}

.output .previous-operand{
    color: white;
    opacity: .9;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.output .current-operand{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? I would expect one indicating there is no delete button in the HTML to be present.

Comment: yeah checked console, 0 syntax errors, everything including the logic is good imo, just doesn't display :/

Comment: I got here the error in console too:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at script.js:125:14.... Just about the line: deleteButton.addEventListener('click', button => { ...

Comment: Hello all, yes there are errors my apologies I wasn't home yesterday, I was working from a friends house and it said 0 syntax errors, but when I got home and connected to WIFI I seen all these errors.

Answer (score 2):

Your project has a some mistakes, in index.html and script, I will activate my solution here and you can compare with your original script

```js
class Calculator {
  constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
    this.clear()
  }

  clear() {
    this.currentOperand = ''
    this.previousOperand = ''
    this.operation = undefined
  }

  delete() {
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString().slice(0, -1)
  }

  appendNumber(number) {
    if (number === '.' && this.currentOperand.includes('.')) return
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString()
  }

  chooseOperation(operation) {
    if (this.currentOperand === '') return
    if (this.previousOperand !== '') {
      this.compute()
    }
    this.operation = operation
    this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand
    this.currentOperand = ''
  }

  compute() {
    let computation
    const prev = parseFloat(this.previousOperand)
    const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand)
    if (isNaN(prev) || isNaN(current)) return
    switch (this.operation) {
      case '+':
        computation = prev + current
        break
      case '-':
        computation = prev - current
        break
      case 'X':
        computation = prev * current
        break
      case '÷':
        computation = prev / current
        break
      default:
        return
    }
    this.currentOperand = computation
    this.operation = undefined
    this.previousOperand = ''
  }

  getDisplayNumber(number) {
    const stringNumber = number.toString()
    const integerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split('.')[0])
    const decimalDigits = stringNumber.split('.')[1]
    let integerDisplay
    if (isNaN(integerDigits)) {
      integerDisplay = ''
    } else {
      integerDisplay = integerDigits.toLocaleString('en', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 })
    }
    if (decimalDigits != null) {
      return `${integerDisplay}.${decimalDigits}`
    } else {
      return integerDisplay
    }
  }

  updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText =
      this.getDisplayNumber(this.currentOperand)
    if (this.operation != null) {
      this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText =
        `${this.getDisplayNumber(this.previousOperand)} ${this.operation}`
    } else {
      this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = ''
    }
  }
}


const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]')
const allClearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]')
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]')
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')

const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  })
})

operationButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  })
})

equalsButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
  calculator.compute()
  calculator.updateDisplay()
})

allClearButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
  calculator.clear()
  calculator.updateDisplay()
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calculator-grid">
        <div class="output">
            <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div>
            <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
        </div>
        <button data-all-clear>C</button>
        <button data-operation>+/-</button>
        <button data-operation>%</button>
        <button data-operation>÷</button>
        <button data-number>7</button>
        <button data-number>8</button>
        <button data-number>9</button>
        <button data-operation>X</button>
        <button data-number>4</button>
        <button data-number>5</button>
        <button data-number>6</button>
        <button data-operation>-</button>
        <button data-number>1</button>
        <button data-number>2</button>
        <button data-number>3</button>
        <button data-operation>+</button>
        <button data-number class="span-two">0</button>
        <button data-number>.</button>
        <button data-equals>=</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Daniel! Thanks I will compare and see what I did wrong. Again, cant thank you enough :)